# Easy online judge task, but struggling to find my implementation error

Tags: c++, debugging, math

I was solving a problem from an online judge. The problem goes like this:

> There are `n` people. They are going to participate in a race. They have to run `s` meters.
>
> Each player `i` has its original speed `v_i`(m/s). Each player runs at speed `v_i` until he runs 80% of the race (`0.8s` meters), and when only 20% (`0.2s` meters) left, the speed changes to `v_i + 10`(m/s). (Surprising!)
>
> The organizers want to know the sum of the distance that each player has run until the top 3 players reached the finish line. You should round down the answer to the nearest integer.

My solution goes like this:

1. Find the third biggest speed `v`.
2. The time when the top 3 is decided is `0.8s / v + 0.2s / (v + 10)`. Let this be `t`.
3. Make an `answer` variable and let it be 0.
4. For each `v_i` smaller than `v`:

   1. If `t`, this player would have run `t * v` kilometers until time `t`. So add `t * v` to `answer`.
   2. Otherwise, this player would have run `0.8s + (0.8s / v - t) * (v + 5)` kilometers until time `t`. So add `0.8s + (0.8s / v - t) * (v + 5)` to `answer`.
5. For each `v_i` not smaller than `v` (`v_i >= v`): Add `d` to `answer`, because they finished the race.
6. Print `floor(answer)`.

But it gets wrong on certain cases. At first glance I thought it was because of precision error, so I used `BigDecimal` of Java instead, but it still gets WA verdict. Is there any error in the logic above, or is it my implementation error?

Here is my code in C++:

```
#include<cstdio>
int main()
{
    int s,n;scanf("%d%d",&s,&n);
    int v[1000],i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(v[i]>v[j])
            {
                int temp=v[i];
                v[i]=v[j];
                v[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    int vv=v[n-3];
    double t=0.8*s/vv+0.2*s/(vv+10);
    double answer=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(v[i]<vv)
        {
            if(t*v[i]<=0.8*s)
            {
                answer+=t*v[i];
            }
            else
            {
                answer+=0.8*s+(t-0.8*s/v[i])*(v[i]+10);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            answer+=s;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",(int)answer);
}
```

Thanks in advance :D

Example:

input:

```
60 8
1 5 4 9 3 8 5 2
```

output:

```
344
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input, output, and expected output?

Comment: Thanks - so it just says "354 is wrong", not "354 should be 355" or similar?

Comment: @JackDeeth, Oh, actually I don't know what the wrong data is.. This is just an example input/output provided in the problem statement. For 90% data my code is correct.

Comment: (fwiw when I run this it comes out as 344… http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tt8CS7f4eEYB17P2)

Comment: @JackDeeth, Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: @miheyan -- It probably comes out "wrong" since you're using floating point values.  Floating point is an approximation and not exact.  The bottom line is that if there is a round-off error, your answer may be different.  Don't answer online judge questions that require you to use floating point -- chances are good your answers will never match.

Comment: What is the value of `answer` before truncating it? If it is something like `344.999999...` try to correct this floating point error by adding a small epsilon, `(int)(answer+1e-10)`, to get the most likely answer. -- You need not the completely sorted array, 3 passes should suffice to get the 3 largest elements.

Comment: what you also could try is using long double. Also: why are you writing your own sort algorithm anyway? `std::sort` or `std::nth_element` should work perfectly well in your case.

Comment: @MikeMB *why are you writing your own sort algorithm anyway* -- Because these online judge sites don't teach how to actually write good code.  If you throw crap code at these sites, and you get the correct answer, then that's all that counts.

Comment: If you _don't know what the wrong data is_, then the problem is not reproducible; it might as well be that that _judge_ is wrong.